# C++, Struct Vector Filling

Tags: c++, pointers, vector, struct

I got a problem filling a struct vector:

Here is the struct:

```
struct indx{
    int inK;
    char* surn;

    indx(int k, char* s) : inK(k), surn(s) {}
    indx(){}
    indx(indx *ind) : inK((*ind).inK), surn((*ind).surn){}

};

std::vector <indx> indexvec;
```

And here is the filling function:

```
void Menu::sortIndex(){
    //Preparacion del fichero indices
    for (int i = 0; i < ag.getArrSize(); i++){
        indexvec.emplace_back(new indx(i, ag.getPersona(i).getSurname()));
    }
    //Ordenacion del fichero indices
    std::sort(indexvec.begin(), indexvec.end(), menor_surn());
}
```

The problem is when fill the vector in the `indexvec[0].surn` is the same as `indexvec[1].surn`.
I've alredy checked that `ag.getPersona(0).getSurename` and `ag.getPersona(1).getSurename` are not the same.

Comment: Provide a [MCVE] please.

Comment: Also copying the `surn` char pointer is wrong. Rather use a `std::string` data type than `char*`.

Comment: Causing memory leak doesn't seem good.

Comment: I cannot use std::string, coz i need the struct to ve POD.

Comment: You need to use `strcpy()` or `strdup()` to make a copy of `surn`.

Comment: Thanks @Barmar ,I used strcpy() and it worked. I post the new code If it can be helpfull for someone.

Comment: Rather than editing the answer into the question, post it as an actual answer, then accept it.

Comment: I found `char *s1 = new char[strlen(ag.getPersona(i).getSurname())];` from the revision history. You forgot to allocate space for terminating null character and will cause out-of-range access.

Comment: `emplace_back(new indx(...))` causes memory leaks, and totally defeats the purpose of emplacement. Just do `indexvec.emplace_back(i, ag.getPersona(i).getSurname());`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution**

```
void Menu::sortIndex(){
    //Preparacion del fichero indices
    for (int i = 0; i < ag.getArrSize(); i++){
       char *s1 = new char[strlen(ag.getPersona(i).getSurname())];
       strcpy(s1, ag.getPersona(i).getSurname());
       indexvec.emplace_back(new indx(i, s1));
   }
   //Ordenacion del fichero indices
   std::sort(indexvec.begin(), indexvec.end(), menor_surn());
```

}

This Is my first post so sorry for my mistakes.

Comment: Almost right. You need to add 1 to `strlen()` to allow room for the trailing null.

Comment: There is no trailing null.

Comment: C strings have to have a trailing null. That's how `strcpy()` knows when to stop copying.

Comment: And it's how `strlen()` figures out the length of the string.